# Calculating all possible left-to-right combinations in which a given word can be segmented

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the formula that gives the exact number of left-to-right combinations in which a word can be segmented. For example, the word `cat` has 4 possible segmentation combinations:

> 1. cat
> 2. c at
> 3. ca t
> 4. c a t

I am not interested in the cases in which letters are scrambled; all combinations of a given words must have the same letter order (from left to right), but different ways to be segmented.

If I am not mistaken, the formula to get the total number of segments should be something like this (apologies for any mistakes in what follows):

> ∑(*i*+(*i*+1)+...*k*), where *i*=1 and *k* is the number of letters of the word

but I don't seem to be able to figure out the formula for the number of *segmentations* these segments may make up to form the actual word.

Does it make sense?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried some examples? What happens for "at", "when", and "while"? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: I do, but it's hard to find a formula for it, especially if you consider that I want to catch also cases in which you have more than one separator between segments (see comment below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letters are fixed, and between each letter there either is a separator between two segments or no separator. For an $n$-letter word there are $n-1$ places where such separators can lie, and hence $2^{n-1}$ segmentations.

At least in this case, there is no need for the sum you propose to count to the segmentations.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Your formula assumes that every combination has exactly *one* separator between segments (and therefore has exactly two segments). What I am looking for would also capture combinations having more than one separator between segments (and therefore more than two segments).

Comment: @RobertP. in that case, suppose you have $n$ separators and $k$ letters. You can permute those separators and letters freely. This leads to $\binom{n+k}k$ possible combinations.

Comment: So, if $n$ = $k$-1, what would the final formula be? Sorry, I'm very bad at combinations and this case seems particularly confusing.

Comment: @RobertP. actually, your understanding of $2^{n-1}$ is wrong. More than two segments does not imply more than one separator beteeen segments, but more than one separator used. With _at most_ $k-1$ separators on $k$ letters $2^{k-1}$ segmentations can be formed; with _exactly_ $k-1$ separators only one segmentation is possible, that where all segments are one letter long.

Comment: you're right, that works! I'd be interested in understanding *why* the base is 2...

Comment: @RobertP. either there is a separator (between a letter pair) or there is not. This makes 2 ways.